# 500 Internal Server Error for my facebook app link

Tags: facebook

I see that this question has been asked before but no solution has been provided.

I am getting nothing but 500 Internal Server Error since yesterday when I use following link:

http://apps.facebook.com/myappID

Yes, I already tried clearing up my cache & cookies so don't even bother asking me this. I have added my app link in the Canvas URL which should show up after I click on the app URL but nothing but that 500 HTTP error. I tried on all browsers and even asked few of my friends too and they said same error.

I thought it was an error on Facebook but I don't see how it's not being fixed for a day now.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

So its a "server-side" error, meaning the problem is not with your PC or Internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server.

Maybe you should contact facebook help center.

Comment: Hi,Yes I have done that just now. Thanks for the reply! :) The weird thing is some people can access it seems like but my visit # has gone down by 80% due to this error. Sigh, I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar situation and found that when I reduced the limit in my GET call to 20 rather than 500 the server responded well.
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/6558867050/posts?limit=20

Comment: What's the "limit on the GET call"?

Comment: If I remember correctly "limit" was the maximum number of posts in the response, i.e. paging.